# Как узнать какой номер у элемента массива?

Tags: python, tornado

```
{% for offer in products %}
  {% if products > 1: %}
  {% continue %}
    <table class="offers">
      <tbody>
  {% end %}
{% end %}
```

Нужно вывести блок `<table class="offers"><tbody>` только один раз, как?

Comment: Не ясно какой шаблонизатор используется. Для jinja это {{loop.index}}

для django это {{forloop.counter}}

Answer (score 2):

Если это стандартный шаблонизатор Tornado, то в нем должны работать функции из стандартной библиотеки - `range`, `enumerate`. Как-то так:

```
{% for index in range(len(products)) %}
  <blah index={{ index }}> {{ products[index] }} </blah>
{% end %}
```